# How to generate two rows of indices for a set

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

Let x_n be a number that depends on n that ranges from 1 to N

Then the set of numbers x_n is usually compactly represented as `\{x_n\}_{n = 1}^N or \{x_n\}_{n = 1, \ldots, N}`

**Now consider the following:**

Let x_{n, k} be a number that depends on n and k.

n ranges from 1 to N

k ranges from 1 to K

Then the set of all these numbers is

`\{x_{n,k}\}_{n = 1, \ldots N \\\ k = 1 \ldots K\}`

[image]

However, I can't seem to produce this in Latex. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\substack`:

```
\[ \bigl\{x_{n,k}\bigr\}_{\substack{n = 1, \ldots, N \\ k = 1, \ldots ,K}} \]%
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `\substack` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\bigl\{x_{n,k}\bigr\}_{\substack{n = 1, \ldots N \\ k = 1 \ldots K}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Using \substack for multiple rows of subscripts.]